# Secure way to create a getter for a char[ ] field

Tags: c++, arrays, string, getter

So im doing an assignment and i have to use a C-style string as a field of my class. I'm trying to create a secure getter for it but i have no idea how to do it.
Field im using:

```
char name[20];
```

So far i tried these things:

```
char* Car::getName() {
    return &name[0];
}
```

^ the only one that works but if im right it returns the address of the field which allows to edit it.

```
char* Car::getName() {
    char ret[20];
    strcpy(ret, name);
    return ret;
}
```

^another approach i tried with no success

So I'd like to ask what's a proper way of creating such getter? (Sorry if its a naive question but i haven't used a lot of C in my life)

Comment: This is not the C I know

Comment: Removed C tag, this is clearly C++.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that

Comment: Consider using a `std::string` and returning a const reference or a copy.  Your second example returns a pointer to a local variable, and that variable ceases to exist at the end of the function leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: I unfortunately cant use string 'std::string' - my assignment requires me to use " c-style as an array of characters "

Comment: If you must use a native char[], then return a constant: const char * Car::getName() const { return name[0]; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the return type to be `const char *`, and make the function itself `const` (to indicate the object is unchanged by the call). Callers can ignore that through casts, but that's on them; this is for correctness, not security.

```
const char* Car::getName() const {
    return &name[0];
}
```

They'll have a pointer to the class internals, but it's explicitly stated that said pointer is to read-only data.

Other options include exposing it as a `std::string` that you construct on demand (`return std::string(name);` with return type `std::string`), or returning a smart pointer of some kind to dynamically allocated memory (equivalent morally to returning `std::string`). Making a copy and returning a dumb pointer (e.g. `return strdup(name);`) is a bad idea, since now you've opened the door to memory leaks; the caller has to manually `free`/`delete` memory.

Comment: I recommend adding "const" after the function name and parameter list: const char * Car::getName() const {}. This means that the class object will not be modified by the function, which is a further guarantee of constancy.

Comment: The alternative is to pass a buffer plus a length. void getName(char *name, int max). Then the const * won't disappear as the class goes out of scope.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: Yes, though I hesitate to impose C idioms like that on C++ code. Of course, real C++ code wouldn't be mucking about with fixed length `char` arrays as class state, so we've burned that bridge already.